# Representing nonelementary functions as a power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the step-by-step process to represent the function $\cos \left(\dfrac t{t-1}\right)$ as a Maclaurin power series?

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x=t/(t-1)$ into the power series for $\cos$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos(x)= 1- \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}- \cdots .
\end{eqnarray*}
Geometrically expand and collect powers of $t$.

The first few tems are 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos \left( \frac{t}{t-1} \right) & =&  1- \frac{t^2}{2(1-t)^2}+\frac{t^4}{24(1-t)^4}- \cdots \\
& =&  1- \frac{t^2}{2} \left( 1+2t+3t^2+  \cdots  \right) + \frac{t^4}{24} \left( 1+4t+10t^2+  \cdots  \right) - \cdots\\
& =&  1- \frac{t^2}{2} -t^3-   \frac{35t^4}{24}  - \cdots\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How should the OP deal with the (powers of) $t-1$ in the denominator(s)?

Comment: I know what the answer should be  1 - (t^2)/2 - t^3 - (35t^4)/24 - ... , but plugging how does plugging t/(t-1) for x get to this?